# Realm.getInstance(this.realmConfiguration) threw 'java.lang.AbstractMethodError' exception

Tags: android, realm

I'm working in a project where I used Realm version 0.87.4. Now I tried to upgrade Realm database version from 0.87.4 to 3.2.1. After resolving some issues I did build successfully using Build->Rebuild option.

So, I run my android application. Unfortunately it throws error.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this.realmConfiguration);
```

realmConfiguration variable is instance of `RealmConfiguration` class.

How to resolve this issue

[Exception detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD73v.png)

Comment: You probably have some other dependency that also brings in Realm, for example `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter`? So the question  is your Gradle dependencies.

Comment: Its Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

Comment: what is the difference between `Realm.getInstance()` and `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`

Comment: I have the same error when minify app

Comment: `Realm.getInstance()` gets an instance using a configuration while `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` gets an instance using the default configuration.

Comment: Please post your `RealmConfiguration` and how you call `Realm.init()`.

Comment: While the various comments about `getInstance` vs `getDefaultInstance` are correct, they are a red herring.  Your problem stems from a bad combination of libraries, in your app.  As @EpicPandaForce says, the issue is your Gradle dependencies.  Try `gradle app:dependencies` ... and please include your actual stacktrace, not a pointer to it.